# Laravel make specific value of column unique

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

`billing_plans` table contains a `default_plan` column. Only one can be chosen as default. But you can edit plans in table. I want to make a binary column, 1 value equals default, 0 is not. But mysql and laravel consider that 0 value is unique too. Is it possible to make only specific value of column unique?

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('billing_plans', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->boolean('default_plan')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
 }
```

Comment: Can you give a simple snapshot of the `billing_plans` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with Mysql ignore **false** value of unique constraint. You need put the column nullable and when it's false put null instead of false.

```php
$billingPlan->default_plan = ($request->input('default_plan'))?:null;
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4617940/2389232