# Insert unique column with dependent column

Tags: mysql, database

I have a unique string column in my database table. The table consists of data column and removed column. If I try to insert a duplicate string into that unique column, it will show duplication error which is what I want. My removed column will indicate 0 as exist, 1 as doesn't exist.

When I try to add the unique string to data column whereby the removed column is 1 (doesn't exist), the query will returns duplication error.

**What I want**

```
id data    removed
1  hello   0
2  haha    1 <- remove column, so data column will ignore unique data
3  haha    0 <- New data
```

**How do I insert the unique string into data column with removed equal to 0?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your `unique` constraint for `data` and `removed` together, not only for `data`.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE `unique_name`(`data`, `removed`);
```

But if you would like to save many `haha` with `1` in `removed` column, then `unique` constraint is not an option for `MySQL`. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617914/how-to-create-a-unique-constraint-on-a-boolean-mysql-column).