# nodejs/mysql - is it possible to make sure there is always exactly one true for all rows

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, unique-constraint

I am using nodejs and mysql.
In my table `event`, assumed that there are currently 3 rows of data.

There should be exactly one featured Event.

GET /event

```
[
 {
    id: 1,
    content: "content 1",   
    isFeaturedEvent: false
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    content: "content 2",   
    isFeaturedEvent: true
 },
 {
    id: 3,
    content: "content 3",   
    isFeaturedEvent: false
 },
]
```

Is it possible to make sure there is always only/at most one `isFeaturedEvent: true`, in server side/database side?
For example, if the third event(id:3) change the value of `isFeaturedEvent` from false to true, it will then throw error.

Comment: Similar question has been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617914/how-to-create-a-unique-constraint-on-a-boolean-mysql-column

Comment: Yes, TRUE / NULL would be the way to go, if you don't want anything more complex (another table).

Comment: @Vaibhaw Agrawal I tried to create new table `FeaturedEvent`, but I am not sure the schema for this table, should it only contain one column(id of table `event`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without a separate data item that's the `id` of the featured event, you could try this.

1. Add an attribute to your model (a column to the table) with the `DataTypes.DATE` data type, including date and time. Let's call it `featured`.
2. Put a unique index on that column, so no two rows can have the same value.
3. To mark a row as *featured*, update the value of that attribute to the current timestamp.
4. To find the featured item, retrieve the rows in descending order of your `featured` attribute and take the first one.

So, your featured item is the one with the most recent `featured` timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table FeaturedEvent with a constraint of having only one row that is having true value. So if you try to insert another row it would throw an error.
To constraint the table to have only one row :

> CREATE TABLE FeaturedEvent  ( ID bool PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE ,  featuredEventID int, CHECK (ID!=false) );

Remove the isFeaturedEvent field from the main table

Refer to answer for creation of table with one row : [How to allow only one row for a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307244/how-to-allow-only-one-row-for-a-table)